# Upgrade 2.5 joomla to joomla 3.0 component not found error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have problem on error loading component after login the administrator page.

Error Messages:

```
Warning
Error loading component: , Component not found

Error loading component: {"admin_style":"","admin_language":"","language":"","editor":"","helpsite":"","timezone":""}, Component not found

Error loading component: {"admin_style":"","admin_language":"","language":"","editor":"","helpsite":"","timezone":""}, Component not found
```

Comment: can you see/use your administration panel?

Answer (score 2):

Joomla 3.0 admin 404 component not found error
Go to administrator/components/componentname
In that you will find file admin.componentname.php 
rename that file to componentname.php (remove admin.)
That’s it error will be resolved, but for compatibility you need to make changes as per the requirements.

Comment: What do you mean "for compatibility you need to make changes as per the requirements"? Is there anything else that needs to be done, other than removing admin.?

Comment: I don't recommend doing that as the first option, as it removes the component. See zkanoca's answer, it helped me. It's about installing the missing extensions using the discover option inside extension manager.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that some components do not look like installed properly. So you'd better check what is not installed:

Assuming you can see administration panel on your screen,

- Open Extensions Manager
- Click on 'Discover' tab-link - If there is nothing listed, click on 'Discover' button above
- Try to find some components that you think might be missing or should be existing but not. For example Smart search, User Login etc.